# Date and Time picker for Tapestry 5.3.7 using Prototype

Tags: java, date, time, prototypejs, tapestry

Tapestry comes with Date picker, which is fine if you want to pick dates only.

However, I'm in need of selecting time as well (date and time filtering).

Due to specific reason, I am not allowed to use jQuery, which is unforutunate, because I've found this neat Date and Time picker: https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Is there a similar, but Prototype based Date and Time picker for Tapestry 5.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Howard's [tapx-datefield](https://github.com/hlship/tapx) library. I've not used it myself but it claims to support date & time. I think it wasn't included in tapestry core because of license incompatability.

Comment: Is there a jar somewhere, I did a quick search on Maven, but found none: http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=tapx

Do I checkout the branch and build it myself, or is there some other way to include the date and time picker only?

Comment: As stated in the github documentation, the maven repo is at http://howardlewisship.com/snapshot-repository

Comment: Is it my imagination or has the tapx project has been removed from every single repo? The only thing that's left is the source code on GitHub.